# Chained await within a single async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios, next.js

```
async function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e.target)

  await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', {username, password})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      const token = res.data.token
      if (token){
        const json = jwt.decode(token) as { [key: string]: string}
  
        await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', { token })
          .then(res => {
            const data = res.data
```

The issue is on this line

`await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', { token })`

My IDE states

> TS1308: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.

It currently cannot compile, I am trying to pass the token value into another axios API call. However this is currently not possible because of the error above. Any clue on how to fix this will be appreciated

Comment: Your function callback for `then()` is not async

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `then` syntax. Write `const res = await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', …);` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` must be directly in an `async` function, you need to make the callback function `async` as well.

```js
async function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e.target)

  await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', {username, password})
    // async here
    .then(async res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      const token = res.data.token
      if (token){
        const json = jwt.decode(token) as { [key: string]: string}
  
        await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', { token })
          .then(res => {
            const data = res.data
```

As Bergi mentioned, there's no point to mix `await` and `.then`, your code could be like this:

```js
async function submitForm(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e.target)

  let res = await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', {username, password})
  console.log(res.data)
  const token = res.data.token
  if (token){
    const json = jwt.decode(token) as { [key: string]: string}
  
    res = await axios.post('/api/<PATH>', { token })
    const data = res.data;
```

Comment: Why would Op need a then() in first place?

Comment: @charlietfl I was trying to explain syntactically how `async` works. For the logic, I added the information after

Comment: @hackape The downvotes were cast before the second paragraph was added.

Comment: Well, even without second paragraph, it's explains why OP's case didn't compiled, which's just what he asked! Getting rid of unnecessary then callback is nice to add, but without that part, the answer is still legit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it is my bad combining await & .then